# Unable to show fancybox title in v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

... sorry, but i have a similar problem with no solution:

i use this code to open a fancybox from inside an iframe.
Here the head-part:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

i attach fancyBox with this code:

```
<!-- Attach fancyBox when the document is loaded.  -->
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox({
        href: this.href,
        width: 1280,
        height: 1000,
        padding: 10,
        type: 'iframe',
        scrolling : 'no',
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        helpers: {
            title : { position : 'bottom', type : 'float' },
            overlay: { css : { 'background' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)' }
             }, // overlay
        } // helpers
    }); // fancybox
}); // click
}); // ready
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

the link on the body-part is the following:

```
    <a title='Sample title' class='fancybox' href='1_BIG.php'>
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

But no title is displayed. :(

When i write the following line to the attach-code the title is showing up, but just statical and this helps nothing:

```
   title : 'just a static title',
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Are you able to pass position : 'bottom' through the title option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are firing fancybox using a manual method `$('.fancybox').click()` then `title` attribute is not picked up so you need to force it adding the API option

```
title: this.title
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dW9d3/)**

**NOTE** : title `type: 'float'` is the default and is ALWAYS at the bottom of fancybox so positioning it has no effect

```
helpers: {
    title: {
        // position: 'bottom', // <== useless if using "float"
        type: 'float' // this is default so you don't have to set it unless is different
    },
    ...
```

Comment: hi JFK...

...and THANK YOU VERY MUCH for the perfect answer. You dont know how long i tried to figure out the problem. Where did u find this info? i think i read the whole fancy-box documentation, but it seems like i have missed this part...

anyway: thank you again!!!